Using templates with chunked HTML in Pandoc
When I create HTML output with Pandoc, usually I pass on a template as argument, e.g.: --template=easy_template.html. These days I started experimented with the chunked output option, using the -t chunkedhtml flag. It works fine, but the templates are not applied to the HTML output, it is all vanilla, non styled text.
How can I apply a HTML template to a chunked output? Do I need to use a different kind of template? If yes, which? Or must I pass the template in a different way to the Pandoc engine?

Silly question. Have you tried passing the flags in, in a different order?

@spikey_richie Changing the order of the parameters/flags indeed produces different results. With the template parameter after the chunked flag part of the styling seems to be applied. However, with that configuration the table of contents is not shown and there is no way no navigate the document.
